# Ratio of a given co-moving length scale to the horizon

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

How does the quantity $aH = \dot{a}$ measures the ratio of a given comoving length scale to the horizon (during inflation say)?

Answer (score 0):

During inflation the Friedmann equation is not applicable, and I am not aware of any particular equation that might be used then to calculate aH=da/dt.

During the times after inflation has completed, the Friedman equation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Detailed_derivation

can be used to calculate the horizon.